# Find out if remote wipe has worked (Google find my device)

Tags: remote-wipe

My phone (Galaxy S7 Edge) was stolen two days ago and up until about 8 hours ago it had been off (or airplane mode was on), I decided that I wasn't seeing that phone again so I opted to erase the device via the "find your phone" section of google my account (the replacement to google device manager, i believe). About 2 hours after I sent the command, the phone synced with my google account.

The phone was offline when I sent the command but I was assured the command would be executed when the phone came online. Presumably it came online when it synced.

Is there any method by which to tell if the command succeeded? The sim is still in the phone and active, I haven't changed the Google password or anything at all along those lines, my phone will still be connected to Google.

EDIT I should also mention that the phone has not been reachable after the sync - but that could be down to the phone being switched off again

Answer (score 0):

If it connected after you had the command prepared for it, it would continue to wipe the phone until all user data and apps were deleted once it synced, the only thing that can stop it after it starts is a force restart in which I believe it would continue trying once turned on again.

Once the phone is wiped there is no user data left including any login credentials, there is no way to know if it was successfully wiped and no way you can track it by yourself using google or any other online tracking solutions. If you still have the SIM active you should contact your provider and they might be able to track the phone with your SIM.